# Good architecture for a moderately simple TCP server

Tags: c, linux, tcp

I am planning on implementing a special purpose TCP server in C on Linux. After doing a little research, it looks like there are a few ways to do this, including single threaded, one thread per connection, and others. For the sockets, there are options like datagram vs stream, and blocking vs non-blocking.

Most of the communication is going to look like:

```
Client: request id [request info]
Server: status id [response info]
```

or

```
Client: request id [request info]
Server: status id [response info]
Client: additional request id [request info]
Server: status id [response info]
```

Where everything is <1kB and most things are <512B. There may be many individual requests in a short time, however.

So, how do I set up the server so it works most effectively (ie, doesn't hog resources, doesn't deny client requests)?

Comment: Does generating the response take a long time ?

Comment: TCP implies that you're using a stream. Datagrams are UDP.

Comment: Do you have an idea of the bandwidth, the number of connections? If the server is not very loaded, why don't you consider using existing protocols (maybe HTTP, or XMLRPC, or SNMP, ...)? I would suggest using textual messages (Json, ....) because they are simpler to debug. (Look at SCGI for a simple protocol example).

Comment: @cnicutar possibly, the server is to allow a client application to communicate with a DBMS and possibly various web services. Basile- probably no more than 100 per second, usually less. The reason I wanted to use TCP was that the content of the message is so simple any more complex protocol would be more complex than it's worth.

Comment: Why C? Do you really want to make things difficult for yourself? Is this some kind of homework? Surely using a more sensible high-level language would be easier (and thus increase developer-performance, which is very important)

Comment: @MarkR I chose c because it really didn't seem like I needed any features of a higher level language. If I end up needing them, I'll just switch to C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your question boils down to performance. Does it?

If so, three questions:

- What's the average/maximum number of clients your server will be handling?
- Is the connection persistent, or clients connect for every X requests?
- How much processing is involved when a client sends a new request?

Anyway, I'd start simple. Make it non-blocking, and single threaded. Profile and stress-test it. Then, if you're not happy with the presented performance, identify the root cause and try to fix it. As ultimate option, scale it to one worker thread per processor core.

If you don't care about reliability and order of delivery, you might want to use UDP.